# SAS 9.3 email attachment

Tags: sas

Since upgrading to SAS 9.3, i'm only able to send emails within rsubmit, which isnt a problem... however i'm unable to attach local files, please can someone assit?

```
RSUBMIT;
FILENAME outmail EMAIL
SUBJECT="Daily report attached"
TO= ("xxxxx@xx.com")
ATTACH= "C:\Users\one\Desktop\Cars.xls";
DATA _NULL_;
FILE outmail;
PUT "Hello All,";
PUT ;
PUT "Please find attached the Cars report.";
PUT ;
PUT "Regards";
PUT ;
RUN;
```

I receive the following error message in the log:

```
ERROR: Error opening attachment file C:\Users\one\Desktop\Cars.xls.
ERROR: Physical file does not exist, /home/one/C:\Users\one\Desktop\Cars.xls.
```

Any help is much apriciated.

Thank you

Comment: Maybe the path to file in `ATTACH` should be as `"Desktop/Cars.xls"` ?

Comment: There's nothing special about SAS 9.3 and emails, as far as I know; did something change about your desktop (OS, permissions, etc.) that might have prevented mail from being sent locally?

Answer (score 0):

Your RSUBMIT is being submitted on a server, so inside the RSUBMIT the paths are local to the server.  Unless it can see your desktop (ie, via a mapped drive) it won't be able to access files on the local machine.  You would have to upload them to the server first.

Comment: I've upgraded to Windows 7 64-bit and SAS 9.3 64-bit from Windows XP and SAS 9.2 32-bit.

Emails wont send locally, therefore requiring a rsubmit 'even though Outlook 2010 32-bit is set as my default email client'.

Systems permissions have not changed and am an administrator.

Comment: Sure, but you still can't access desktop-local items from the rsubmit.

Comment: Is there any easy way to upload to SAS, attach to email and then delete?

Comment: That depends on details you haven't provided.  What kind of connectivity do you have between the RSUBMIT box and the local box?  At minimum you could upload a dataset and then re-export it, if that's reasonable for your project; perhaps you could use FTP or something else via SAS.